# Show all errors above a form with bassistance plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am using this plugin for form validation:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

The problem is, it displays validation error next to each form field. I would like to display all errors above the form fields.

Is that possible? I cannot find this possibility mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it is, the option you are looking for is errorLabelContainer (used in combination with wrapper).

The example given [there](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) is:

```
$("#myform").validate({
   errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
   wrapper: "li",
   submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!") }
});
```

So in the div (or whatever element has the id "messageBox"), you will get a `<ul>` with all the errors listed, wrapped in `<li>` which you can then style as you want with an external css.